# Wordpress Posts 2 Posts plugin: using callback in fields using key default_cb not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I've begun to use the posts to posts plugin by Scribu, awesome plugin!!! I need to use a callback function to get metadata related to the connected post, but the callback doesn't work.

```
p2p_register_connection_type( array(
    'name' => 'subdishes_to_groceries',
    'from' => 'subdishes',
    'to' => 'groceries',
    'title' => 'Sub Ingredients',
    'admin_box' => array(
        'context' => 'normal'
    ),
    'fields' => array(  
        'yield_unit' => array( 
            'title' => 'Y Unit',
            'type' => 'text',
            'default_cb' => 'get_groc_y_unit', // CALLBACK          
        ),
        'yield_price' => array( 
            'title' => 'Y Price',
            'type' => 'text',
            'value' => 'asdasdasd',             
        ),          
        )       

) );    

function get_groc_y_unit( $connection, $direction ) {

    global $post;
    $key = ( 'from' == $direction ) ? 'p2p_to' : 'p2p_from';
    $post = get_post( $connection->$key );
    setup_postdata($post);

    return the_title();

}
```

What is $connection here? I checked Posts 2 Posts wiki but couldn't figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can anyone who knows a thing or two about Posts to Posts plugin please help.

Comment: Ok, issue resolved! 'default_cb' only works when a connection is created and not when existing connections are loaded in admin pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, issue resolved! 'default_cb' only works when a connection is created and not when existing connections are loaded in admin pages.

Also, I created my own custom key and hacked the core files a bit to allow using post related metadata from callbacks while loading existing connections. Basically, I needed to show static metadata in separate columns with connection metadata. p2p_connected_title and p2p_candidate_title weren't enough to help so I had to hack core. Also, don't use setup_postdata in this situation, it messes up the UI!